# Cocos2d get screens current center position?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So i have a sprite which moves in each direction and the camera follows that sprite using this code

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:(_cars) worldBoundary:_trackssss.boundingBox]];
```

And i need to get the current center position of the screen or cameras location XYZ....

Could you please tell me how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, this is what you're looking for.-

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width / 2, self.contentSize.height / 2);
```